# python Individual X and Y Label for Subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to have individual labels for the x and y-axis of each subplot. I tried the following:

```
# First create some toy data:
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x**2)

# Creates just a figure and only one subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_title('Simple plot')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ydata("Y")
```

...but I get:

> AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_xdata'

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `ax.set_ydata` instead of `ax.set_ylabel`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set the X and Y labels, you should use`ax.set_ylabel('Y')` rather than `ax.set_ydata("Y")`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a good english but , are you ok with that ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# First create some toy data:
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x**2)

# Creates just a figure and only one subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_title('Simple plot')

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your contribution and welcome to Stack Overflow. :) I was asking how to add a label for subplots, not for plots. I made a silly mistake as you can see from the accepted answer.